# Ultima Online Classic Client cannot play

Tags: ultima-online

I have windows 7 and I downloaded and installed the classic client from the official website. I am running it as an administrator. I have tried running it in compatibility modes but nothing solved the problem. When I click the play button client closes, computer starts running slowly but nothing happens. It does not appear in running applications list in task manager. If I try to open the client again most of the time it says "Patch Client has stopped working". If the client starts, nothing changes. What could cause the problem?

Comment: Can you share the error that you mentioned?